# How to enable Cancel button on UI Searchbar iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using an UI search bar into my iPhone application, I would like enable Cancel button of Search bar at the time of view did load but not able to do so as its gets activated when a user starts editing the search bar. To be more precise I would to achieve the serach functionality that has been provided by Apple in Stock application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using not just the search but the searchDisplayController as well then it is done like this:

> self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

Hope this helps.